Psycopg2 Library For AWS Lambda
I am trying to add psycopg2 add as a Lambda layer but it gives this error when I test the Lambda function:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'psycopg2'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": []
}

Where can I find psycopg2's compiled version for AWS environment?
I tried the download and zip 3.11 psycopg2 version from https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2v and I add this zip as a Lambda Layer into AWS. Runtime versions are same.

How did you create the zip archive? awslambda-psycopg2 only talks about packaging it in your main lambda alongside your own source code. For Layers you need to package it under a directory called python or python/lib/python3.x/site-packages. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html If you didn't package the zip file correctly, then python won't be able to find your libraries from the layer.

You don't need any specific version for AWS environment. Just follow the below mentioned steps.
1 - Create a virtual python environment in your local system. Let's say you named it Project.
2 - Activate the newly created environment and install psycopg2 in it using pip install psycopg2.
3 - Put your main python handler (let's say it's lambda_function.py) in the Project directory.
4 - Create a zip file of the Project directory and upload it as your lambda function.
Make sure that your handler (lambda_function.py) starts with the below code.
import os
import sys

CWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(CWD, "Lib"))

import psycopg2
# Rest of your code starts from here

Hope this helps!
